# Laravel save dynamic input in database with foreign key

Tags: mysql, laravel, dynamic, input, laravel-5

I am using Laravel 5.1

I want to save inputs value of dynamic created inputs in my database.

I basically create the dynamic inputs with this line:

```
...
for(var i = 1; i<slider.value; i++) {
          +'<div class=\"input-group\">'
             +'<input name=\"input-chapter-name[]\" name="" type=\"text\">'
             +'<input name=\"input-chapter-start[]\" name="" type=\"text\">'
             +'<input name=\"input-chapter-end[]\" name="" type=\"text\">'
          +'</div>'
}
```

My two models look like this:

```
<?php
    class Chapters extends Model
    {
        protected $table = 'chapters';
        protected $fillable = ['chapter_name' ,'input-chapter-start', 'input-chapter-end'];

        public function product()
        {
            return $this->belongsTo('App\Product');
        }

    }
```

```
class Product extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'products';
    protected $fillable = ['email', 'title', 'filename', 'inputMpg', 'number_of_chapters'];

    public static $rules = [
        'email'                => 'required|email|max:50',
        'title'                => 'required|max:50',
        'filename'             => 'required|max:50',
        'input_mpg'            => 'required',
        'number_of_chapters'   => 'required',
        'input-chapter-name'   => 'required',
        'input-chapter-start'  => 'required',
        'input-chapter-end'    => 'required'
    ];

    public function Chapters()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Chapters');
    }

}
```

And in my Controller I save (try to save) the data like this:

```
 $product->save();
 $Chapters->chapters;
 $Chapters->product()->associate($product);
 $Chapters->save();
```

And get the following error:

> ErrorException in Grammar.php line 118: Argument 1 passed to
>   Illuminate\Database\Grammar::parameterize() must be of the type array,
>   integer given, called in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\lariApp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Query\Grammars\Grammar.php
>   on line 672 and defined

**Edit:**

my current controller looks like this:

```
<?php

class ProductController extends Controller
{

    protected $request;

    public function request(Request $request)
    {
        $this->request = $request;
    }

    public function createProduct(Request $request, $productID)
    {
        $product        = new Product;

        $data = $request->only('email', 'title', 'filename', 'number_of_chapters');

        # Validate Input
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), Product::$rules);

        # if validation fails return Erros
        if($validator->fails())
        {
            return Redirect::back()->withInput()->withErrors($validator);
        }

        $product->fill($data);

        if($product->save())
        {
            $product = Product::find($productID);

            foreach ($request->input('chapters', []) as $chaptersData) {
                $chapters = new Chapters($chaptersData);
                $chapters->product()->associate($product);
                $chapters->save();
            }

            return redirect()->route('root')->with('message', 'WIN')->withInput();
        }
        else
        {
            return redirect()->route('newProduct')->with('message', 'Error')->withInput();
        }

    }

}
```

And my route:

```
Route::post('create/{productID}', ['as' => 'createProduct', 'uses' => 'ProductController@createProduct']);
```

Comment: Is line `118` the `$chapters->product()->associate($product);` line?

Comment: The 4 lines from your controller dosen't make sens. This is a problem for sure and don't know what you whant to do.

Comment: nope line 118 is not that line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that controller should looks like:

```
public function createProduct(Request $request)
{
    $data = $request->only('email', 'title', 'filename', 'number_of_chapters');

    # Validate Input
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), Product::$rules);

    # if validation fails return Erros
    if($validator->fails())
    {
        return Redirect::back()->withInput()->withErrors($validator);
    }

    $product = new Product($data);
    if($product->save())
    {
        foreach ($request->input('chapters', []) as $chaptersData) {
            $chapters = new Chapters($chaptersData);
            $chapters->product()->associate($product);
            $chapters->save();
        }

        return redirect()->route('root')->with('message', 'WIN')->withInput();
    }
    else
    {
        return redirect()->route('newProduct')->with('message', 'Error')->withInput();
    }

}
```

where view is more like that:

```
...
for(var i = 0; i < slider.value; i++) {
    +'<div class=\"input-group\">'
        +'<input name=\"chapters['+i+'][chapter_name]\" type=\"text\">'
        +'<input name=\"chapters['+i+'][input-chapter-start]\" type=\"text\">'
        +'<input name=\"chapters['+i+'][input-chapter-end]\" type=\"text\">'
    +'</div>'
}
```

This will help You create dynamiclly multi $chapters and associate with product model's.

All You need is to pass product's id in in the route to this controller action (while defining the link):

`route('create-multi', $product->id)`

or just

`<a href="create-multi/{{$product->id}}">`

which is defined like:

`Route::post('create-multi/{productId}', 'Controller@createMultiChapters')`

Comment: BTW, I think you don't need to save the product since you will need to manually assign the chapter_id. Associate the product first and then save only the chapter (which will automatically save the associated product).

Comment: Yes I change this a little bit. Think that You should save `$chapter` because it won't save associate automatticly (it only set foreign in model without saving it).

Comment: Well this is just an example :) You need to pass the `$id` variable somehow.    Past your whole controller method.

Comment: hmm, ok could you show me a snippet of how you do it, I am not that experiened

Comment: Ok I've updated the entry so You can check if You better understand it.

Comment: Ok thanks alot I will check it out and give you a message afterwards

Comment: how would I put them in my fillables / rules like this?
`chapters[][chapter_name]`

Comment: You won't to do that. Your fillable is ok. that why I put the input in: `foreach ($request->input('chapters', []) as $chaptersData) {` <- it itterates trought the chaperts  as it's in my view example: `chapters['+i+'][chapter_name]` where `i` is the itterator. Laravel knows that and making a multidimension array from it.

Comment: ok got it, now I get this message:

`ErrorException in ProductController.php line 94:
Non-static method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::newInstance() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context`

Comment: ok I'm sory with that should be: `new Chapters($chaptersData);`

Comment: ok I understand, now I get this: `SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'product_id' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `chapters` (`input-chapter-start`, `input-chapter-end`, `product_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (00:00:00, 01:00:00, , 2016-04-28 08:26:46, 2016-04-28 08:26:46))` probably because of the empty parameter right?

Comment: ok, You have bad foreign key... just define in the relation model method here: `return $this->belongsTo('App\Product', 'product_rom_id');`

Comment: and add it to `$fillable`

Comment: If I dd($product) it returns me null

Comment: I do not think I am passing them, thus do you mean if I already created another product object?

Comment: Thus would you like continuing this in the chat?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110487/discussion-between-john-does-legacy-and-filip-koblanski).

Comment: My bad... You want to create product... so You're not passing any id. I will edit the correct answer in the moment. Please past part of your view with form.